# finding 'only' the first preceding sibling that matches

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was wondering how to find only the first preceding sibling that matches a specific criterial (ie. class='a')? Right now when I run the search it finds all of the nodes that match. Here is an example of what I mean:

```
tr class = 'a'
tr class = 'b'
tr class = 'b'
tr class = 'a'
tr class = 'b'
tr class = 'a'
tr class = 'b'
tr class = 'b'
tr class = 'b'
```

For every instance of b I am trying to find the first preceding tr that has class 'a', but when I run the code it finds all of the preceding tr that have class 'a'. I also cannot use tr[1] because there are varying lengths of class 'b' below each class 'a'. Here is what I am entering:

```
//tr[@class='b']/preceding-sibling::tr[@class='a']
```

I can post my actual code if needed, but I think this example says it all.

Comment: What should the correct output be?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You want the first of a collection? Just use `find_element()` or `find_elements()[1]`.

Comment: It is an attribute of the tr[@class='a'] -> @Blender                                                 There is a list of 200+ <tr> values. Some are the title values (class 'a'). For all the class 'b' values I would like to find what class 'a' value it falls under, but when I run the code above for example it gives me all of the class 'a' values out of the 200 - I only want one. Every group of class 'b' vaules has a specific class 'a' value related to it, and that is what I am trying to get. The class 'a' value is always preceding.

Comment: Shouldn't that be something like `soup.select('tr.a')[0]` ?

Comment: @alace: I don't think XPath supports duplicates. You'll have to perform a different XPath query starting at each `tr.b`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the question but, if the html is something like this:

```
<table>
   <tr class = 'a'>
      <th>1</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class = 'b'>
      <th>2</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class = 'b'>
      <th>3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class = 'a'>
      <th>4</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class = 'b'>
      <th>5</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class = 'a'>
      <th>6</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class = 'b'>
      <th>7</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class = 'b'>
      <th>8</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class = 'b'>
      <th>9</th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

If I execute this:

```
elList= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@class='b']/preceding-sibling::tr[@class='a'] ")

print("len List: " + str(len(elList)))

for el in elList:
    print ("value: " + el.text)
```

The output is:

```
len List: 3
value: 1
value: 4
value: 6
```

Comment: This is exactly it. But what if I was starting at the class containing 9 and wanted only to get 6 without knowing how many tr away it was?